# Problema ao conectar Access no VisualStudio

Tags: banco-de-dados, visual-studio, conexão, microsoft-access

Criei um pequeno banco de dados no Access e estou tentando fazer a conexão com o VisualStudio, porém dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Unrecognized database format 'c:\Users\wss\desktop\dbteste.accdb'

Como soluciono isso?

Comment: Está conseguindo abrir normalmente o Banco? Faça um compactar e reparar e tente novamente.

Comment: @Denis Já fiz isso e continuo o erro

Comment: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Users\wss\desktop\dbteste.accdb"

Comment: Tenta com essa connection string

Comment: Você tá tentando conectar via código ou por alguma wizard do VS?

Comment: Para o Access 2003 e anterior, o pacote requer o provedor OLE DB do Microsoft Jet e para o Access 2007 em diante, o pacote requer o provedor OLE DB para o Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine. Veja em https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc280478(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Então, aparentemente resolvi mudando a extensão para mdb, não sei se era isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei mudando a extensão ao salvar o arquivo de: `.accdb` para `.mdb`

Grato!